# Pair correlation function of the QHE "plasma"

Tags: plasma-physics, correlation-functions, quantum-hall-effect

I am trying to teach myself the theory of quantum Hall effect, and realized that I can not reproduce a basic textbook result.
Let me closely follow Girvin's Les Houches lectures (http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9907002 ).

Consider wave function of the $\nu=1$ filled state (formulas 1.83-1.88):
\begin{equation}
\psi(z_1,\dots z_N)=\prod\limits_{i<j}(z_i-z_j)e^{-\frac14\sum\limits_k |z_k|^2},
\end{equation}

According to Laughlin's suggestion we can treat the norm of the wave function as a partition function of a classical two-dimensional Coulomb plasma (1.89):
\begin{equation}
Z=\int d^2z_1\dots d^2z_N|\psi(z_1,\dots z_N)|^2,
\end{equation}
with a potential of the following form (1.90-1.91):
\begin{eqnarray}
|\psi(z_1,\dots z_N)|^2&=&e^{-2 U}, \\
U&=&-\sum\limits_{i<j}\ln |z_i-z_j|+\frac{1}{4}\sum_k |z_k|^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Now we define the two-point correlator of this classical plasma as an integral over all but two arguments of the squared wave function (1.111)
\begin{eqnarray}
g(r)=\frac{N(N-1)}{n^2Z}\int dz_3\dots dz_N |\psi(0,r,z_3,\dots z_N)|^2,
\end{eqnarray}
where $n$ is the uniform density of particles, which, according to Girvin, can be evaluated exactly and gives (1.112):
\begin{equation}
g(r)=1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}.
\end{equation}

This integration is what I'm puzzled about.
I tried to do it for few particles ($N=3,4,5$) analytically using Mathematica, analytically by hands and numerically, and I always obtained something like
\begin{equation}
g(r)=e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\cdot r^2P(r),
\end{equation}
where $P(r)$ is some low order polynomial with coefficients depending on $N$.

So, while the "correct" pair correlator behaves like $\lim g(r)\rightarrow 1$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$, my correlator dies off at infinity.

Does anyone know how to reproduce the classical result, or a good textbook/paper where this calculation is done in details?

Girvin himself gives some hint on how to do it (Ex. 1.15 on p.37 in his lectures), but to be honest I do not understand it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that we expect $g(r)$ to vanish for large $r$ except in the thermodynamic limit $N\rightarrow\infty$. You should be able to calculate $g(r)$ for arbitrary $N$ and then take $N\rightarrow\infty$. I'll try to provide details in an answer soon.

Comment: Thank you, @user37496 !
It is a very good point indeed. Looking forward to your detailed answer.